# Can't Connect to Facebook Based Spotify Account

Tags: python, spotify

I'm using the Pyspotify Spotify client. In order to connect to a session, they supply a class `SpotifySessionManager`, which takes `username` and `password` parameters. However, I and many people connect to Spotify using Facebook, and once you have done so Spotify does not provide a way to get a more traditional user name and password. Any Pyspotify users know how to work with this common form of Spotify user authentication?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can find the username for your Facebook-linked Spotify account by:

1. Go to http://www.spotify.com/
2. Log in using your Facebook account
3. Go to your account overview

The account overview should show your "native" Spotify username, which you can use with pyspotify/libspotify.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and solved it by creating a `spotify device password` through my spotify profile page: https://www.spotify.com/fi/account/set-device-password/

This password is than accepted together with the device user name by pyspotify.